# Properly disconnect client (telnet) from ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I want a simple server socket to accept a client and read some texts and disconnect the client from itself. As a client I'm using a telnet for now, because in the future I will create a custom program.

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(SERVER_SOCKET_PORT); 
    Socket s = ss.accept();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null || line == "" || line == "q") {
            log("-- breaking the loop");
            break;
        }

        printf("**%s%n", line);
    }
    reader.close();
    s.close();
    ss.close();
```

The problem I'm having is the while loop never breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that isn't how you compare `String`(s) for equality. Second, I would prefer `String.isEmpty()` to testing for equality with `""`. Finally, you can use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close` everything. Something like,

```
try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(SERVER_SOCKET_PORT);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.isEmpty() || line.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            System.out.println("-- breaking the loop");
            break;
        }

        System.out.printf("**%s%n", line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true) {
    line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null || line == "" || line == "q") {
```

> The problem I'm having is the while loop never breaks.

So the peer never

- closes the connection
- sends an empty line that compares to `""` via the (incorrectly applied) `==` operator
- sends a string consisting only of `"q"` plus a line terminator.

The normal way to write this loop would be:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.isEmpty() || line == "q") {
        log("-- breaking the loop");
        break;
    }

    printf("**%s%n", line);
}
```

But if the peer never closes the connection or sends the `"q"` there's no way this loop will ever exit. Are you *sending* anything that would produce either of those conditions?

> disconnect the client from itself

This is meaningless. Please restate.